# Как убрать два ноля в номере телефона

Tags: php, php7

У меня возникла проблема при вводе телефона +380098.

Есть номер телефона +38002415645, и мне нужно убрать 2 и больше нуля подряд после +38, и заменить на один 0.

Comment: Какой в этом смысл, почему нельзя сразу вводить с одним нулём? Нужно всё парные нули заменить на единичные или только когда они идут после "+38"? Можно, пожалуйста, для полноты понимания, больше примеров: как есть - как должно быть.

Comment: Да регуляркой... она ж простейшая. https://regex101.com/r/p7YSMy/2

Comment: или так https://regex101.com/r/oA4Mre/1